# Sending the same value multiple times

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I want to save multiple serial numbers with just one form. That means as an example that you have like 4 input fields where you can scan these serial numbers 1 field is required the others don't have to be filled this looks like that:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware('guest');

    request()->validate([
      'serialnumber' => 'required',
      'serialnumber',

      'member_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    Ausleih::create($request->all());


    return redirect()->route('borrow.index');

}
```

So next up is the view where the input comes from:

```
 <div class="card-body">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('borrow.store') }}">
        @csrf

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="serialnumber" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Scan serialnumber') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="serialnumber" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('serialnumber') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="serialnumber" value="{{ old('serialnumber') }}" required autofocus>
                <br>
                <input id="serialnumber" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('serialnumber') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="serialnumber" value="{{ old('serialnumber') }}" autofocus>

                @if ($errors->has('serialnumber'))
                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('serialnumber') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="member_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Scan your member card') }}</label>
          <div class="col-md-6">

            <input id="member_id" type="password" class="form-control" name="member_id" required>


            @if ($errors->has('member_id'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('member_id') }}</strong>
            </span>
            @endif
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ __('send') }}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see I just made another input field to save up more than one serial number. The problem is that I just get one value, not both can someone help me out with this? What do I have to change?

Comment: The `id` must be unique in the same document

Comment: Just as an *FYI*, Chrome has starting classing multiple ids with the same name as an error in the console so you can take a look in their too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `id` attribute must be unique in the same document, so remove the duplicate ones or replace them with common classes.

You need to use the name as an array like `name='serialnumber[]'`, then in your `store` action loop through them like :

```
foreach($request->serialnumber as $serialnumber){
   //Use every $serialnumber as you want here
}
```

Your validation could be like :

```
$request->validate([
    'serialnumber' => 'required|array|min:1',
    'member_id'    => 'required'
});
```

So the serial name should be an array that contains at least one item.

Comment: what comes in the foreach something like    foreach($request->serialnumber as $serialnumber){
        'serialnumber' => 'required' }?

Comment: Check my update... and let us know how your table structure looks like in the DB

Comment: @Jaexz for info regarding validating arrays in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: I meant what do i put in the foreach loop? I am not the best in laravel but im giving my best in learning it i really appreciate every help!! Thanks for all of your replies!

Comment: Let us know how your table structure looks like in the DB, we have to know how and where you want to store those serials

Comment: That will be done in 3 steps: You've to listen first, then answer our question, then we could help.